# Which ethanol derivatives display the gauche effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, conformers

> How many of the following ethanol derivatives of the form $\ce{GCH2CH2OH}$ have a more stable gauche conformer compared to their anti conformer?
>
> $G =  \ce{F}, \ce{Cl}, \ce{OH}, \ce{NH2}, \ce{OMe}, \ce{NHMe}, \ce{NMe2}, \ce{NO2}$

I was sure that $\ce{F}$, $\ce{OH}$, $\ce{NH2}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ display the gauche effect. I'm not so sure regarding all the other groups: all of them seem bulky and won't form hydrogen bonds with the $\ce{OH}$ group on $\ce{C}_1$. How many of the other substituents are capable of displaying this effect? Also, is there a quantitative way to determine if the gauche conformer would be more stable than the anti conformer?

Comment: Nice question, I am pretty sure that ethylene chlorohydrin also has gauche form more stable. Also I think for knowing most stable form we need to optimize the molecular geometry on different levels of quantum chemistry, starting from a conformer halfway between staggered and eclipsed. Levels are like HF/def2-TZVP, PBE-D3/def2-TZVP... Don't know direct way to find that. Further, I think G=NHMe would also form more stable gauche form (not sure). What's the answer given?

Comment: The answer is 7. I'm ignoring it for now until I have an explanation.

Comment: Then, I guess, all except NMe2.

Comment: @Zenix More probably NO2 - it would have H-bond but with 6-membered ring. BTW even N(CH3)2 isn't all that bulky.

Comment: See [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2860(93)07968-3)

Comment: See the last page [here](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~madhavr/CHM102/Lec8.pdf)

Comment: @YusufHasan Thanks a lot! could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this source](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~madhavr/CHM102/Lec8.pdf), there is evidence for the gauche effect for most of these groups on basis of intramolecular hydrogen bonding:

> [image]

I tried looking for a similar evidence for 2-nitroethanol, and found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320717238_It_Is_Important_to_Compute_Intramolecular_Hydrogen_Bonding_in_Drug_Design/figures?lo=1) on the same:

> [image]
>   Figure 4. OCCN gauche structures with an intramolecular H-bond for 2-aminoethanol (7) and 2-nitroethanol (9); Conformations 8 and 10 indicate disrupted H-bonds after rotations by approximately 120º about the O-C axes

So it seems like all the groups shown here can show the gauche effect on the grounds of intramolecular hydrogen bonding,and so your answer should be **8**